# Creating an instance of goog.ui.Button with an image file

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm relatively new to the Google Closure library and my current obstacle is getting a button to render programmatically with an image (as opposed to text).  I've tried adding a img tag as the content of the button:

```
var image = goog.dom.createDom('img', { 'src' : 'foo.png' });
var button = new goog.ui.Button(image);
```

However, although a blank button does render in the page no image appears.  An inspection of the generated HTML shows a button tag with no contents.

I've also considered adding a style attribute that specifies `background-image`.  However, it's not clear to me how to accomplish this through the Button API.

Any thoughts or examples on how to accomplish this?  Appreciate the help.

EDIT: Here's the solution I arrived at with Dave Paroulek's assistance:

```
var button = new goog.ui.CustomButton();
button.render(goog.dom.getElement('button-row'));
var style = button.getElement().style;
style.backgroundImage = 'url(foo.png)';
style.backgroundPosition = 'center center';
style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CustomButton seems to work:

```
var image = goog.dom.createDom('img', { 'src' : '/images/foo.png' });
var button = new goog.ui.CustomButton(image);
```

I'm not sure specifically why it doesn't work with Button, but noticed that Button renders a `<button>` and CustomButton renders several `<div>` elements that are styled to look like a button, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Also, if you want to use background-image, then you can try this:

```
var div = goog.dom.createDom('div', { 'class' : 'icon goog-inline-block' });
span = goog.dom.createDom('span', { 'style': 'vertical-align:middle'}, 
                              'Button with css image');

button = new goog.ui.CustomButton([div, span]);
var btn2 = goog.dom.$('button2');
button.render(btn2);
```

Then, add css like this:

```
.icon {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  background-image: url(/images/foo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll give the first suggestion a go with using a CustomButton.  The problem with the second is that the path to the image file is determined programmatically, so I'd have to apply the background-image via a style attribute directly on the button's element.

Comment: Had a chance to confirm CustomButton works as you describe.  Also managed to attach style information to each button -- I'll document my final solution above.